# groupingBy operation in Java-8

Tags: java-8, apache-spark, tf-idf, text-classification

I'm trying to re-write famous example of Spark's text classification (http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/classifiying-documents-using-naive-bayes-on-apache-spark-mllib/) on Java 8.

I have a problem - in this code I'm making some data preparations for getting idfs of all words in all files:

```
    termDocsRdd.collect().stream().flatMap(doc -> doc.getTerms().stream()
                                .map(term -> new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>()
                                .put(doc.getName(),term)
                                .build())).distinct()
```

And I'm stuck on the groupBy operation. (I need to group this by term, so each term must be a key and the value must be a sequence of documents).
In Scala this operation looks very simple - **.groupBy(_._2)**.
But how can I do this in Java?

I tried to write something like:

```
    .groupingBy(term -> term, mapping((Document) d -> d.getDocNameContainsTerm(term), toList()));
```

but it's incorrect...

Somebody knows how to write it in Java?

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do something like this:

(`import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`)

```
Map<Term, Set<Document>> collect = termDocsRdd.collect().stream().flatMap(
 doc -> doc.getTerms().stream().map(term -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(doc, term)))
.collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toSet())));
```

The use of `Map.Entry`/ `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` is due to the absence of a standard `Pair<K,V>` class in Java-8. `Map.Entry` implementations can fulfill this role but at the cost of having unintuitive and verbose type and method names (regarding the task of serving as `Pair` implementation).

---

If you are using the current Eclipse version (I tested with LunaSR1 20140925) with its limited type inference, you have to help the compiler a little bit:

```
Map<Term, Set<Document>> collect = termDocsRdd.collect().stream().flatMap(
 doc -> doc.getTerms().stream().<Map.Entry<Document,Term>>map(term -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(doc, term)))
.collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toSet())));
```

Comment: Thanks Man for answer! But when I try to use Your code in Eclipse - I got compile error - **Type mismatch: cannot convert from** `Map<Object,Set<Object>>` **to** `Map<String,Set<Document>>` Naturally, if I change `Map<String,Set<Document>>` to `Map<Object,Set<Object>>` Eclipse return error, that type Map.Entry hasn't got getKey() and getValue(). I found very similar example of this situation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423078/java-8-grouping-by-from-one-to-many), and Lukasz Wiktor got the same error in Eclipse. Could You tell me whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: I’m afraid, Eclipse’s Java-8 support still needs more time to mature.

Comment: Thanks Man! I'll try another IDE.